# Размер текста в SwiftUI

Tags: ios, текст, swiftui

У меня есть текст (который может состоять как из одной буквы, так и из большого количества строк). Как можно узнать и записать в переменную высоту и ширину всего текста?

Comment: ровно как и измерение любого другого вида вьюх - через GeometryReader

Comment: @Andrew это понятно, но я не совсем понимаю, куда его надо засунуть. GeometryReader надо же вроде внутри вьюхи писать

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-provide-relative-sizes-using-geometryreader

Comment: @Andrew это не совсем то. В статье описывается как настроить размер рамки, относительно размера вьюхи, а мне надо узнать размер текста, то есть GeometryReader надо внутрь Text() засунуть

Comment: По линке именно то, что тебе нужно, просто ты это неправильно понимаешь. Обворачиваешь геометри ридер вокруг текста и geometry.size.width и есть ширина твоего текста.

Comment: @Andrew я уже дошел до другого ответа, но спасибо, буду знать

Comment: я перепроверил, все же, я обманул. Вот здесь есть ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57577752/4423545

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот код, если размер и высоты, и ширины неизвестен:

```
func labelSize(for text: String) -> CGSize {
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    ]

    let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)

    let constraintBox = CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)

    let rect = attributedText.boundingRect(with: constraintBox, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], context: nil).integral

    return rect.size
}
```

Если известна ширина или длина, то надо в параметрах функции добавить известную величину и подставить ее в `constraintBox`